# After login using google (oauth) how to redirect to the home page (desired page)?

Tags: python, django, redirect, oauth, google-signin

I want to redirect the user to the desired page after he logins using the Google Login.

I am successfully able to goto the signin page where user enter his/her account. But after I select the gmail account it shows, error `relation "social_auth_usersocialauth" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "social_au...`

Comment: explore Django's LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, also you have to set redirect URL in your google app dashboard

Comment: I tired but now it is saying ```Authentication process canceled```

Comment: you need to add some traceback then, also did you run the migration for socialauth app?